# Are the following assertions about Go packages accurate?

Tags: include, go, package

Are the following assertions about Go packages accurate?

1. `import "package_name"` imports all files from the directory called package_name assuming is found in $GOPATH, a variable that holds the users go directory, or in the standard go installation directory tree.
2. files within the package_name directory will usually state `package package_name`. But they are not required to. In fact, `import "package_name"`, would also import a file including the line `package foo` if the file was found in the imported package_name directory.
3. All functions that are Capitalized will be accessed through the name given in the package package_name declaration--for instance:

`package_name.Function_in_file_that_declares_package_name` or `other_than_package_name.Function_in_file_that_declares_other_than_package_name`

1. User defined packages are command-line `go install`-ed from the within the package directory. However, go will refuse to install a directory named identically to its builtin package directories. For instance you cannot install a strings directory since go already has a strings directory for the builtin package "strings." However, the user can append functions to the strings package without altering the builtin strings folder, by creating a my_strings directory and the placing a file that states `package strings` within it. Now, `import my_strings` will load the extra user-defined strings functions accessed with `strings.Function_name`.

In summary, the `import` keyword is used to load files from a given directory. And the keyword `package` creates a namespace to access Capitalized functions from outside that file.

Am I understanding all of the above correctly?

Comment: It seems a bit like you assume that Go packages and import statements work a bit like include directives and the namespace keyword in C++  (hint: they don't). Try to not draw parallels to C++ and read the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec) instead.

Answer (score 4):

1. The argument of "import" is an import_path, not a package name. It makes exported entities from a package found in `$GOPATH/src/import_path` available in the file scope where the "import" clause appears.
2. All *.go files, except `*_test.go` files and files with `// +build ignore`, in a single directory must say the same name in the `package name` clause or the go build system will reject it.
3. Not capitalized, but belonging to the Unicode category Lu. Not functions but any TLD entity.
4. No, you can go-install any package from any directory using its import path. Yes, packages from the stdlib have priority and cannot be "overriden". However, you can effectively "replace" a stdlib package using eg. `import strings "github.com/foo/mystrings"`. However, the effect is local/file only.

In summary, no, import is used to make entities from other packages available in the file scope. The keyword "package" creates no namespace. The effect of "import" is file-scoped, see the preceding sentence and usually the imported entities are referred to by qualified names. That qualifier is a sort of namespace, but note that not the "exporter" (`package foo`) controls that. Instead the control is at the "importer" side: `import whatever_local_name "whatever_import_path"`. The default qualifier is the basename of the import path, though.

*"Do we all agree?"*

Not at all.

Comment: I appreciate your corrections--they are helpful. Thank you. This all started off with me wondering if it was possible to append functions to the strings package without adding files to the go src directories. For instance, I want a strings.Transmutate function. I wanted to add a $GOPATH/src/strings directory and then add transmutate.go. But go won't allow me to install using that folder name. I also don't want to over-ride the built-in strings package, just want to add to it. My solution, which seems to work, was to create a $GOPATH/src/my_strings folder and place transmutate.go inside.

Comment: transmuate.go includes a package strings declaration. Then import "my_strings" provides strings.Transmutate functionality. Is this a reasonable solution?

Comment: No, this is not a reasonable solution. Package strings is one of the standard library packages. You should not "add" to them and having your own `package strings` makes your code unreadable as now suddenly `string.Trim` is no longer stdlib's strings Trim function but maybe deletes arbitrary files. Just name your package properly, e.g. `package transmutate` and export `func Do(s string) string` or that like.

Comment: I see. My hack solution actually blocks the standard library package. I didn't realize that. Not good. So there is no way to add to a standard library other than actually inserting a file into the standard library directory, which would eventually lead to confusion. But the alternative--having more than one package containing functions that manipulate strings isn't optimal either. I wish one could append to the standard library without harming/hiding the existing code.

Comment: @Tim The Go concept is different. People see import strings and know "he's gonna use the strings package". If you want to have custom functionality, the easiest way for other people to understand this is to have a package named tim.example/tim/strings that contains your own string functions. Then others see your code and the "import timstr "tim.example/tim/strings" statement and immediately know "aha! I have to checkout package tim.example/tim/strings to figure out what all these timstr functions are doing.

Comment: You can actually just go into the src/strings directory and start adding to the strings package, then sudo go install. Then your code becomes part of the standard package. The upside is all string related functions are in the strings package, the downside is that your version of go has been modified and won't match the go installations on other machines. So, even though it is not ideal to have 2 separate packages involving strings, it is probably the best solution in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

Even if it sounds harsh: Almost all assumptions are completely wrong.

Take a look at http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names and http://golang.org/ref/spec#Packages and do not think of `import` as the Go equivalent of C's `include`.

Go's packages are more like precompiled libraries and an `import "some/path/foo"` is more like linking in foo.a (but also makes exported entities available under - normaly - `foo.SomethingExported`.

Now have a look at http://golang.org/doc/code.html and it should become clear what packages are and how they are used.